# AWS does not launch new spot instances: capacity oversubscribed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Since a few days I get "capacity-oversubscribed" on aws and no matter what I'm doing, I do not get no new spot instances:

*capacity-oversubscribed: Your Spot request with price 1.39 was not fulfilled as the number of Spot requests with equal or higher prices exceeds the available capacity in this pool.*

The thing is that I already increased my maximum price to insane high prices like 2$ and above just to make it work, but I still get this error.

I understand that the prices are going crazy at the moment - does this simply mean that aws does not have resources available?

Comment: What instance type are you trying to launch?

Comment: ...and in which region?

Comment: ...and in which availability zone and for which operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that aws simply does not have capacity atm for the given availability zone.

Comment: Is there any status api to check the availability by zone and instance type?

Comment: When you work with AWS, 99% of your time is dedicated to access the correct error message. In this case, I followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#RetrievingErrors.